# MVC 4 Razor Checkboxlistfor formatting issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, checkboxlist

I was trying to implement a 'CheckboxListFor' method but am having some issues with formating in which the text for the checkbox does not align on the side of the checkbox but instead is below the checkbox.
[image: Here is what it looks like]

Code in View:

```
     @{ 
         var htmlListInfo = new HtmlListInfo(HtmlTag.table, 4, null, 
                                             TextLayout.Default, TemplateIsUsed.No);
     }


      @Html.CheckBoxListFor(model => model.KeywordIDs,
                                     model => model.Keywords,
                                     model => model.KeywordId,
                                     model => model.Name,
                                     model => model.SelectedKeywords,
                                     htmlListInfo
       );
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello, Please refer this link http://mvccbl.com/Examples?PostedCities.CityIDs=2&PostedCities.CityIDs=3&PostedCities.CityIDs=4. I doubt the issue is with `HtmlTag.table` it should be `(HtmlTag.vertical_columns`

Comment: That's where I pull my info from to begin with and using the verical_columns gives me the same problem except that the columns are compressed even further instead of evenly spaced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok gr8.. Minor change.
Try this code.

have to apply css to fix it.

```
<style type="text/css">
    label
    {
        display: inline-block !important;
        padding: 5px !important;
    }
</style>
@{ 

    var htmlListInfo = new HtmlListInfo(HtmlTag.table, 4, null, TextLayout.Default, TemplateIsUsed.No);

    @Html.CheckBoxListFor(model => model.PostedCities.CityIDs,
                      model => model.AvailableCities,
                      city => city.Id,
                      city => city.Name,
                      model => model.SelectedCities,
                      htmlListInfo)
}
```

let me know your comments.

Comment: Thanks that works. Didn't know about !important and that  will help in the future.